# change select option with var change

Tags: javascript, html

I want to change my select's option when one of my var change.
I start with this.
JS :

```
test = new Array();
```

HTML :

```
<select>
</select>
```

And I search to change my select when I add element in test like this : 

JS :

```
test.push({value:1,innerHTML:opt1})
test.push({value:2,innerHTML:opt2})
```

HTML :

```
<select>
<option value=1>opt1</option>
<option value=2>opt2</option>
</select>
```

Can I do that with eventlistener or anything else?

Comment: First, don't use 'new Array()' but 'var test = [];' Then you wan't to watch your array for any change ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways you can do this:

a) Don't make the variable a simple variable, but an object with a setter function that also executes the DOM changes you want.

```
function Test() {
    var self = this;
    self.value = [];
    self.set = function(new_obj){
        self.value.push(new_obj);
        // DOM changes here
    }
    return self; 
}

var test = new Test();
```

Then when you want to change the variable, write:

```
test.set({value:1,innerHTML:opt1})
```

b) Use an mvc framework like knockout.js (which exists to solve this exact problem)

Answer (score 1):

You can proxy push method to add your own logic to it:

```
var test = new Array();
var _push = test.push;

test.push = function(el) {
    // add options to select here
    _push.call(this, el);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this...
    var tt =['sdfs','sdgfg'];
    Object.observe(tt, function(){ debugger; }); 
    tt.push('sdfds');

Comment: You've got it backwards: OP wants to know when the *variable* changes and then update the select, not know when the select is changed. There is no second select.

Comment: you are correct nnnn....!!!!Then..Try this below code:
var tt =['sdfs','sdgfg']
Object.observe(tt, function(){ debugger; });
tt.push('sdfds')

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<select id="select1" onchange="changeHandler(this)">
    <option value="1" >1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
```

JS:

```
document.getElementById('select1').value = 2;
function changeHandler(select){
    alert(select.value);
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/NourSammour/hp9ryekp/1/

and to watch your array and trigger the re-render you can use

```
Array.observe(test, function(changes) {
  // render
});
```

I hope this help :)

Reference:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/observe

Comment: This processes change events on the select element. The OP asks how to know when the *array* changes.

Comment: @nnnnnn thanks for your reply, i edit my answer and hope this help!

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea to answer with a method that is obsolete, was not widely adopted and likely will be removed from the few browsers that support it. I'm not sure why a feature that was never supported by Mozilla browsers is in the Mozilla documentation.